# How to seed/upload images in KeystoneJS 6?

Tags: javascript, graphql, keystonejs

Using the example [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/blog), if I then add an image field to Post:

```js
// schema.ts
import { list } from '@keystone-6/core';
import { select, relationship, text, timestamp } from '@keystone-6/core/fields';

export const lists = {
  Post: list({
    fields: {
       featureImage: image(),
    }),
    /* ... */
  },
  /* ... */
});
```

How can I then adjust the `seed/index.ts` file to upload an image form the local drive?

```js
// seed/index.ts
await context.query.Post.createOne({
    data: {
        ...postData,
        featureImage: { /* ??? What goes here ??? */ }
    },
    query: 'id',
});
```

Or otherwise, how can I programmatically add images so that keystonejs is aware of them?

Answer (score 1):

Got from here https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-discussions-archive/discussions/54

```
// prepareToUpload.ts
import mime from 'mime'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { Upload } from 'graphql-upload'

export const prepareToUpload = (filePath: string) => {
  const filename = path.basename(filePath)

  const createReadStream = () => fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  // @ts-ignore
  const mimetype = mime.getType(filePath)
  const encoding = 'utf-8'

  const image = {
    createReadStream,
    filename,
    mimetype,
    encoding,
  }

  const upload = new Upload()
  // @ts-ignore
  upload.resolve(image)

  return upload
}
```

```
  await context.query.Film.createOne({
      data: {
        name: filmData.name,
        imagePoster: {
          // imagePoster MUST by a object with `upload` field
          upload: prepareToUpload(__dirname + '/folder_to_local_file/here.jpg'),
        },
      },
      query: 'id',
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get reference from here https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/main/packages/cloudinary/src/test-fixtures.skip.ts

```
import { exampleValue } from '../test/@keystone-6/cloudinary/src/test-fixtures.skip';
....
const { context } = req as typeof req & { context: Context };

const data = await context.db.Db_Modal_Name.createOne({
  data: {
    field: exampleValue(),
  },
});
```